# Java -> Python with AES

Tags: java, python, aes

I searched a lot in the web for a solution for this problem. I´m using Python 3.4 and pyCrypto to use AES. Java already included ciphers with AES, but for some reason I can´t get Python and Java to work with each other. I don´t need to post my code, because I already lost all my hope of trying it. I´m just asking for an example of how to do it and I dont care if it´s CBC, CFB or anything else, just a working example.

Comment: `I don´t need to post my code..` I would recommend to post a sample code else your question will be flagged as Off-topic. Other than that the advantage of posting the sample code is that the Stack overflow(SO) users can quickly copy paste your code and try to find a solution instead of writing a sample code themselves. This saves time.The more you help SO, the more SO will help you!

Comment: As I said in my post already. I didn´t find a way of doing it so I cant post any code.

Comment: Please have a look at this question and you'll surely realize what I am trying to convey.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670368/python-aes-decryption Notice how the user structured his/her question and presented a clear view of his/her problem without getting any down votes. :)

Comment: I see what you mean, however my problem is, that i don´t have a proper code to use between Java and Python, so I just want some help by figuring it out. I could imagine, that Java SecretKeySpec hashes the key before using it. I don´t what Java´s AES does different than pyCrypto´s AES

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at these entries.

[Decrypt an AES encoded message (encrypted in Python) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763720/decrypt-an-aes-decoded-message-encrypted-in-python-in-java)

[python AES encryption java decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417092/python-aes-encryption-java-decryption)

Are you encrypting in Python and decrypting in Java or what do you mean by working together?
Rethink your question and try to make it a little bit easier to understand so it is possible to post a "working" solution

Comment: I already looked up those posts, but what i mean is just a working class, where i can encrypt and decrypt in either way (from Python to Java and back again). I tried so much, but I cant find a way of doing it.